Efficient cover of $\mathbb{Z}_N$ with bit shift operation
I have a simple electronics device that has no processor in the usual sense, but it has a finite memory, call it $N$ bits, with a bit-shifting operation. We got onto the question of whether we could create a loop that would efficiently produce every unsigned $N$-bit integer using this operation.  We do not require that we see the integers in order, just that we see all $2^N$ of them.  We prefer to see each integer only once, but we would accept seeing some more than once if necessary. We call an algorithm with fewer repeats more "efficient" than one with more repeats.
It is essentially trivial to design a loop that will visit every integer, but to do it efficiently has become surprisingly hard, and I am interested in learning more about any tools that might help solve it.
Being more precise, we start with 0 on all $N$ bits.  The operation available shifts all bits already in the number one position in the direction of more significance ("left-shift") and puts either a 0 or a 1 on the least significant bit. (This differs from a standard left-shift operation in many computer systems, which typically shift only a 0 into the least significant position.)  This gives us a sequence
$a$ in which $a_0 = 0$ and, for each $k\geq0$, $a_{k+1} = 2a_k + b_k \mod 2^N$ where each $b_k$ is either 0 or 1, depending on which value we choose to shift into the least significant position at the $k+1$ step.
The problem is to choose a specific sequence $\left\{ b_k \right\}_{k=0}^{K-1} $ of length $K$ such that $\left\{ a_k \right\}_{k=0}^{K} = \mathbb{Z}_{2^N}$ and $K$ is as small as possible.
As mentioned earlier, existence of a sequence that achieves the equality is trivial.  Starting from 0, we can put any given combination of the $N$ bits in place using $N$ steps, and we can always get back to 0 with $N$ more shifts in which we choose to put 0 on the least-significant place.  Doing it that way, however, revisits many numbers.  For example, to get 1 with that algorithm, we do $N-1$ shifts in which we insert 0 at the least-significant place and then one shift in which we insert 1 at the least-significant place. In that case the sequence $a$ starts
$$ \begin{array}{lcr}a_0 & = & 0 \\ a_1 & = & 0 \\ \dots\\ a_{N-1} & = & 0 \\ a_N & = & 1 \end{array} $$ We call that inefficient because the value 0 repeats.  Other than trial and error though, I am not sure how to optimize the process.  Any hints, theorems, or tools that might help?

De Bruijn sequences ??? ... https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/akherim/VanlintWilson.pdf

A suitable linear feedback shift register will cycle through all the $N$ bit combinations with the exception of all zeros. If you start from all zeros, giving such an LFSR a non-zero initial impulse will then cover the others.
